# LDS viewpoint on decafinated tea and coffee

Tags: lds, diet, doctrine-and-covenants

Does the prohibition of consuming caffeine found in Doctrine and Covenants 89 allow the LDS adherents to drink decaf tea/coffee?

Comment: Great question, if I do say so myself... I asked something similar that was closed as a duplicate of the one above: [Does the LDS Church prohibit the use of caffeine?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/50962/21576)  The answer to your question is actually found there: "This includes decaffeinated coffee, and cold coffee and tea. It does not include chocolate, hot chocolate, or warm milk."

Comment: Many thanks; my question isn't a duplicate because I wish for clarification on the LDS viewpoint specifically about decaffeinated tea and coffee.

Comment: caffeine isn't mentioned in the Word of Wisdom, hot drinks are which have been specified as tea and coffee

Comment: Caffeine is not prohibited in the Word of Wisdom: "Finally, another small correction: Despite what was reported, the Church revelation spelling out health practices (Doctrine and Covenants 89) does not mention the use of caffeine.  The Church’s health guidelines prohibit alcoholic drinks, smoking or chewing of tobacco, and “hot drinks” — taught by Church leaders to refer specifically to tea and coffee." http://www.mormonnewsroom.org/article/mormonism-news--getting-it-right-august-29